# Angular material table collapse/expand complete table so only header is visible

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I got many material tables on my page, to make browsing easier I would like to make a complete table collapse/expand when clicking on the header (or a small button inside the header). I find many examples on how to expand table rows but I need to collapse the complete table.

Comment: add your code with sample snippet.

Comment: i suggest you that use expansion panel and use table after `mat-expansion-panel-header` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

When tapping collapse, I assign an empty array to the data source of that table. when clicking expands I reassign the original array to the data source of that table. This way my header&footer cells which contain totals for the table are still visible but the inner cells are not.

Something like the code below should allow this behavior:

```
collapse(index: number) {
if (this.contracts[index].tabledatasource.data.length == 0) {
  this.contracts[index].tabledatasource = new MatTableDataSource(this.stockArray[index]);
} else {
  this.contracts[index].tabledatasource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of using mat-table inside mat-expansion panel.

I gave it a try and I believe it would satisfy your requirement.

Please check if this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-inside-expansion) satisfies your requirement.

Comment: That is indeed close to my wanted behavior. but my table headers & footers actually contain data that should still be visible. I was thinking about assigning an empty array to the tabledatasource when collapsed and reassigning the original array when expanded. still have to try that though.